# Why Google doesn't search in wikipedia history section?

Tags: google-search

I'm just registered and have some stupid question.
Why google doesn't show information from "view history" pages on wikipedia?
For example, on [this history page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Microservices&action=history) if I google any text I [won't get](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awikipedia.org%20%22Alter%3A%20author%2C%20url.%20Add%3A%20url%2C%20author-link.%20Removed%20URL%20that%20duplicated%20unique%20identifier%22&oq=site%3Awikipedia.org%20%22Alter%3A%20author%2C%20url.%20Add%3A%20url%2C%20author-link.%20Removed%20URL%20that%20duplicated%20unique%20identifier%22) result.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website engine specifically requests that these pages not be indexed. The history page  has a header tag recognized by search engines:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
```

(`noindex` excludes the page's direct content and `nofollow` also tells the search crawler to ignore any further links *from* this page. The latter attribute may also be attached to individual <a> links.)

One possible reason is that search engines might not be able to distinguish "current" and "historical" pages easily, so the results might get flooded by obsolete data that you wouldn't be able to remove.

Another reason is that MediaWiki stores history in delta-compressed format, and the older a history item is, the more CPU it takes to decompress it. (AFAIK there are periodic "full" checkpoints so that it won't spiral into infinity, but it is nevertheless a non-zero resource usage.) Multiply this by possibly hundreds or thousands of revisions for every single wiki page, and the crawler might quickly overload the server.

Finally, aside from the history section, Wikipedia also uses the `/robots.txt` file to exclude certain URLs from being indexed. For example, [its robots.txt file](https://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt) excludes all "Vote for deletion" threads, "Username change request" pages, and such.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is exhaustive and helpful information.